# What is the proper way to add or correct a word in another person's quote?

Tags: editing

I am trying to add a missing word in another person's quote.  What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: +1 for having a better title.

Comment: Can you give an example? Is it a function word like "to"?

Comment: You could handle it two ways: add a word in square brackets, or insert *(sic)* or *[sic]* at the location of the missing word. From MW: *sic*: intentionally so written —used after a printed word or passage to indicate that it is intended exactly as printed or to indicate that it exactly reproduces an original <said he seed [sic] it all>

Answer (score 1):

Surrounding the added word(s) with square brackets will do the trick.